# How to save HTML5 data- attribute to database using PHP?

Tags: php, database, html

I was wondering if and how I can save an HTML5 `data-` -attribute directly to my database using PHP?

I have a a button that creates a list item in a `<ol>` (ordered list). Within every created list item, I store some information using the HTML5 `data-` attribute. Now I would like to save this with PHP to my database.

Is it possible to do that, or should I find another way.

- I would really like to be able to use this data-attribute, as it doesn't take up session, cookie-space or something else with limited amount of data. Also this makes it possible to do everything on the client until it is saved.

Comment: Sure `$.post('myScript.php', {data: $('li.some-list-item').data('foo')});`

Comment: You can save it to a database with an AJAX call and a PHP script. Alternatively, you could save it to the browser's LocalStorage or IndexedDB. It depends what you want it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use AJAX.

Using AJAX :

Use a bit of Javascript before you open the PHP file.

You could use something like `variable = document.getElementById('IdOfYour<ol>tag').getAttribute('data-something')` to get the contents of your **data** attribute.

Then you open your PHP file using `xmlhttp.open('GET','YourPHPFile.php?dataAttr=' + variable ,false/true')`

And in your PHP file  you could just use `$_GET['dataAttr']` to access the data from your Data Attribute